# how to dom parser html table which containing "<" symbol in php

Tags: php, curl, dom, html-table, html-parsing

I want to make curl in php to get the data in html table on this website: https://bri.co.id/web/guest/deposit-interest-rate.
Here's the code I was trying:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
$url = "https://bri.co.id/web/guest/deposit-interest-rate";
$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 5;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
$html = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->validateOnParse = true;
$dom->formatOutput = true;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

@$dom->loadHTML($html);

$table = $dom->getElementById('_Deposit_Rate_Display_Portlet_idrRate');

$row = $table->getElementsByTagName('tr')[1];
//var_dump($row);

$cols = $row->getElementsByTagName('td');
echo 'NOMINAL -> ' . $cols->item(0)->nodeValue. '<br />';
echo 'JANGKA WAKTU -> ' . $cols->item(1)->nodeValue.'<br />';
echo 'SUKU BUNGA COUNTER -> ' . $cols->item(2)->nodeValue;

?>
```

the result is:

```
NOMINAL ->
JANGKA WAKTU -> 1
SUKU BUNGA COUNTER -> 4.75%
```

I want the result is:

```
NOMINAL -> <100 Juta
JANGKA WAKTU -> 1
SUKU BUNGA COUNTER -> 4.75%
```

the problem is the data which contain "<" symbol not showing its show empty string.
How to dom parser "<" symbol so can show the output "<100 Juta" ?

Comment: What does the HTML look like?

Comment: The issue is the **<**, which should be encoded as an HTMLEntity (**&lt;**).  Because it is not encoded, the node isn't parsing correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This will get the values - but it's not an ideal approach because if the HTML on the page changes, it will fail.

```
<?php

// Get the HTML
$url = "https://bri.co.id/web/guest/deposit-interest-rate";
$html = file_get_contents($url);

// Find the Rupiah header and discard everything before that
$rupiah = strpos($html,'<h2> Rupiah </h2>');
$chop = substr($html,$rupiah);

// Find he start and end of the Rupiah table
$tableStart = strpos($chop,'<table');
$tableEnd = strpos($chop,'</table>');

// Get the Rupiah table
$table = substr($chop,$tableStart,$tableEnd-$tableStart);

// Get the body of the Rupiah table
$tbodyStart = strpos($table,'<tbody>');
$tbody = substr($table,$tbodyStart+7);

// Get the rows
$rows = explode('<tr>',$tbody);

// Loop through all the rows and when you find the first blank one, get the cells
foreach ($rows as $r) {
        if (trim($r) !== '') {
                $cells = preg_split('#<td[^>]+>#',$r);
                break;
        }
}

// Loop through all the cells and echo out their contents (without any HTML tags)
foreach ($cells as $c) {
        if (trim($c) !== '') {
                echo strip_tags($c).PHP_EOL;
        }
}
```

Comment: then how to make it an ideal ?

Comment: Find a different way to get the rates. Is there an API/RSS feed you could read? If this is a school project, the code is good enough. It does work. For every piece of code you write, you have to decide how much time you want to spend on it after you get it working. Als, things change, so today’s perfect code may not work tomorrow.